# change a value from the List using java8

Tags: java, java-8

I want a value get nullified before sending to UI.

```
public class MedicalInfoVO {
    private Integer medicalDeoId;
    private List<MedicalCoverageVO> medicalCoverages;
    private List<MedicalSignsSymptomVO> medicalSignsSymptoms;
}

public class MedicalSignsSymptomVO {
    private Integer medicalSignsSymptomId;
    private Integer symptomId;
    private String symptomType;
    private Integer medicalInfoId;
    private Integer diagnosisId;
   private String diagnosisValue;
}
```

I need the medicalSignsSymptomId and medicalInfoId get be nullified before send back to the Service call.

```
medicalInfoVO = retrieveMedicalInfoDetails(authorizationId, claimId);
if(null ==medicalInfoVO || null == medicalInfoVO.getMedicalDeoId()){
    medicalInfoVO = retrieveMedicalInfoDetails(authorizationId, null);
    medicalInfoVO.setClaimId(claimId);
    medicalInfoVO.setMedicalDeoId(null);
    if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(medicalInfoVO.getMedicalSignsSymptoms())) {
        List<Integer> medicalSignsSymptomIdList = medicalInfoVO.getMedicalSignsSymptoms().stream()
                .map(map -> map.getMedicalSignsSymptomId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        medicalSignsSymptomIdList.clear();
        List<Integer> medicalInfoIdList = medicalInfoVO.getMedicalSignsSymptoms().stream()
                .map(map -> map.getMedicalInfoId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        medicalInfoIdList.clear();
    }
}
```

When I do it with stream functionality the object value is still not getting cleared.

Suppose the obejct MedicalSignsSymptomVO  have medicalSignsSymptomId as 3,
I need assign null to it. same for medicalInfoId as well.

Can I know how this can be done using stream functionality, instead of using the foreach functionality.

Comment: You are clearing the local variable lists `medicalSignsSymptomIdList` and `medicalInfoIdList` instead of the lists in `medicalInfoVO`, which you probably intended to.

Comment: @vlumi Can you help me how to change the above stream functionality

Comment: your requirements clearly contradict to what you've written. "I need assign null to it." means you need to change a particular object's field, not to remove the object from the list

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: @bharathi please, show how you see "the foreach functionality"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do, but basically the following is "streamy:"

```
    medicalInfoVO.getMedicalSignsSymptoms().forEach(mSSymptoms -> {
            mSSymptoms.setMedicalSignsSymptomId(null);
            mSSymptoms.setMedicalInfoId(null);
    });
```

One could combine it as follows:

```
    Set<Integer> medicalSignsSymptomIdList = medicalInfoVO.getMedicalSignsSymptoms().stream()
            .map(mSSymptoms -> {
                Integer id = mSSymptoms.getMedicalSignsSymptomId();
                mSSymptoms.setMedicalSignsSymptomId(null);
                mSSymptoms.setMedicalInfoId(null);
                return id;
            }) 
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I used a set here, which seems more logical.

Not necessarily good style, to combine too many things in a stream, for better maintenance. Here: changing elements and return a new list.

Comment: Thanks for the help. At least you understood my question

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending objects to UI, you might not need to set values to null manually.
If you are using Jackson, you can simply put `JSONIgnore` to ignore fields when object is being serialized/deserialized.
e.g.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MedicalSignsSymptomVO {
    @JSONIgnore
    private Integer medicalSignsSymptomId;
    private Integer symptomId;
    private String symptomType;
    private Integer medicalInfoId;
    private Integer diagnosisId;
   private String diagnosisValue;
}
```

In case you need those fields serialized else where then you can use forEach method as described by [@Joop Eggen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56557709/3291897)'s answer.